# Using java combine rgb channel and output channel

Tags: java, visualization, rgb, bufferedimage

I have already output three channels of the image but seems wrong according to color

```
public class RGB {
   public static int getR(int pixel) {
       return(pixel >> 16  & 0xff);
   }

   public static int getG(int pixel) {
       return (pixel >> 8  & 0xff);
   }

   public static int getB(int pixel) {
       return (pixel & 0xff);
   }

   public static int combine(int r, int g, int b) {
       int rgb = (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
       return rgb;
   }
}
```

Did I shift wrong? what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Using the java.awt.Color class as a reference, they change a few things:

```
public int getRed(int pixel) {
    return (pixel >> 16) & 0xFF;
}

public int getGreen(int pixel) {
    return (pixel >> 8) & 0xFF;
}

public int getBlue(int pixel) {
    return (pixel >> 0) & 0xFF;
}

public static combine(int r, int g, int b) {
    return combine(r, g, b, 255);
}

public static combine(int r, int g, int b, int a) {
    return ((a & 0xFF) << 24) |
            ((r & 0xFF) << 16) |
            ((g & 0xFF) << 8)  |
            ((b & 0xFF) << 0);
}
```

I based that combine off their constructors. It's quite a bit different, and they have parentheses in different places for their getters.